# overflow problems on Safari Mobile despire overflow on body / wrapper or html trick

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, safari, overflow

after reading and reading different threads on stack about the overflow problem I needed to decide to open an own thread.

**The basic problem**

```
#wrapper
footer
 .char
  img
```

The img overflows the footer, #wrapper, body and html on x-axis. So I gave the body overflow-x: hidden; AND overflow-y: auto. The result is its fine on Chrome and Firefox. It works. But not on Safari Mobile (SM).

Could it be because the SM feature is you cant disable the zoom and this has any impact to the x-axis scroll manner? Or is the overflow-x also disabled on SM?
Or do any Bootstrap option hamper my mission? I didnt see anything in Chrome's developer tool.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ps. I have a jQuery snippet which do exactly the same as the css. Both give the body the overflow properties. The css dont work. If I activate the jQuery snippet (it changes the values because a 100x100% menu and turn them back to x hidden and y auto if menu is closed) it works on SM. hmm ...